# Arrange numbers to 5 x 5 table, with some constraints

Tags: mathematics

Arrange numbers 1 to 25 to each cell, so :

[image]

- Difference between 2 adjacent numbers (horizontally and vertically) is bigger than 1 and smaller than 6
- The bigger-smaller sign is correct between 2 adjacent numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
>   4 >  2 <  5 >  1 <  3
>   ^    ^    ^    ^    ^
>   9 >  7 < 10 >  6 <  8
>   ^    ^    ^    ^    ^
>  14 > 12 < 15 > 11 < 13
>   ^    ^    ^    ^    ^
>  19 > 17 < 20 > 16 < 18
>   ^    ^    ^    ^    ^ 
>  24 > 22 < 25 > 21 < 23
> ```

Reasoning:

> the lower rows numbers are bigger that the upper rows for each column.
>  This means we can split the numbers in groups of 5 like this:
>  (1,2,3,4,5) goes on the first row, (6,7,8,9,10) go on the second row and so on.  and on each column row[i] = row[i-1] + 5.
>  We just need to find a way to match the columns to the signs.
>  Most probably we can permute the columns 2 & 4 and 1 & 5 (both permutations at once).

Comment: columns 2 and 4 cannot be permuted without 1 and 5 permuted as well, because then number 2 would be adjacent to number 3, which is not allowed

Comment: @elias. That's what I meant. I thought that `and` would clear it. Apparently I need to change this.

Comment: oh, sorry. maybe it was just my misinterpretation

Answer (score 3):

Besides the solutions listed in @JamalSenjaya's answer, I think

> ```
>   4  2  5  1  3
>   9  7 10  6  8
>  14 12 15 11 13
>  19 17 20 16 18
>  24 22 25 21 23
> ```

,

> ```
>   4  2  5  3  1
>   9  7 10  8  6
>  14 12 15 13 11
>  19 17 20 18 16
>  24 22 25 23 21
> ```

,

> ```
>   5  2  4  1  3
>  10  7  9  6  8
>  15 12 14 11 13
>  20 17 19 16 18
>  25 22 24 21 23
> ```

and

> their mirrorings around a vertical axis.

are

> six correct solutions.

Comment: There is 2 more correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

These 2 are the last another correct answers

> ```
>   3  1  4  2  6
>   8  5  9  7 11
>  13 10 14 12 16
>  18 15 19 17 21
>  23 20 24 22 25
> ```

and it's mirror arround vertical axis

> ```
>   6  2  4  1  3
>  11  7  9  5  8
>  16 12 14 10 13
>  21 17 19 15 18
>  25 22 24 20 23
> ```